# To Make My Outer Loop be Aware of Existence of the Inner Loop

Tags: xml, xslt, loops

I think my title basically describes what I stuck at now in XSLT.But to be more precise, what I mean is "How to make the outer loop be aware that the inner DOES get executed or not in XSLT". Please pardon me since I am a beginner in this field.

Firstly, my initial xml is a blank one, and my XSLT is basically going to grab data from loads of xml data files, and create a resulting xml file, with the tags that I want. Specifically, the problems I am concerning happen in two templates "Outer" and "Inner", and these two templates are actually loop structure themselves, they are trying to loop through every row of certain xml files. The control of flow is straight-forward: I call Outer in my main XSLT and then we enter a "for-each" loop of Outer, and within each run of this Outer, I will call "Inner", so it is a Loop-within-Loop Structure.

For now, we can ignore all other things but only know that once I enter the outer loop, I will create a "HL" Segment, and then Inner gets called and entering the inner loop, and for each run of Inner, I will create a "HL" segment too. One thing to be noted it that, Inner cannot be entered unless certain criteria is met, so there can be situations that Inner is not entered at all, and all the HL segment is created in Outer alone.

It is this HL segment that I want to count, I will share a small fragment of code to let you have an idea.

Outer Loop:

```
<xsl:template name="Outer">
  <xsl:for-each select="$rechca//d_claim_rechca_export_xml_row">
    <xsl:variable name="rechca_claim_no" select=claim_number/>
       <HL01>
         <xsl:if test="$indicator=0">                                    

              <xsl:value-of select="position()+1>
          </xsl:if>
       </HL01>
    ....

  <xsl:for-each select="$rechcf//d_claim_rechcf_export_xml_row">
   <xsl:if test="claim_number=$rechca_claim_number">
     <xsl:call-template name="Inner">
      <xsl:with-param name="HLcounter" select="position()+1"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:if> 
  </xsl:for-each>

 </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>
```

Inner Loop:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="$rechcf//d_claim_rechcf_export_xml_row[claim_number =$claimno and sequence_number = 1]">
 <Inner>
 <HL>
   <HL01>  
      <xsl:number value ="position()+$Hcount"/>
    </HL01>
    ....
```

Currently, there are two rows in $rechca, and only one in $rechcf that satisfy the two loops, so the Outer Loop repeats two times and Inner just gets executed one time. Therefore, the desired output should be

```
<Outer>  
  <HL>
    <HL01>2</HL01>
  </HL>
     <Inner>
         <HL01>3</HL01>     
     </Inner>
  <HL>
    <HL01>4</HL01>
  </HL>
 </Outer>
```

But currrent output is:

```
 <Outer>  
  <HL>
    <HL01>2</HL01>
  </HL>
     <Inner>
         <HL01>3</HL01>     
     </Inner>
  <HL>
    <HL01>3</HL01>
  </HL>
 </Outer>
```

If there are no this inner Loop, things will be perfect. But currently the Outer Loop is not aware of the existence of the Inner Loop: Once Inner gets called, then when it returns the control to outer Loop, the  at the top should not contain the "position()+1" but "position()+2" instead (Since Inner got called once before entering this new Outer, so a new HL segment was created in there). As you may see, I created a variable called "indicator". In Java/C++, I would just update this indicator to another value other than 0, every time we enter inner, set it to one. Then doing a test at HL01 of Outer to determine correct value to be added to position().

Really stuck here, please kindly help! Thanks.

Comment: @Robert: Just provide your source XML document (as minimal as possible) and the wanted result and also explain any rules that must hold -- then we will show you a solution. Your main problem is that you are thinking as an imperative language programmer and you are trying to implement impossible solutions, not even being aware how a simpler, functional solution can be found.

Comment: @Dimitre: The problem is that, the code is really long. Can I email you plz?

Comment: @Robert: We don't need "the code". We need a simple XML document and the wanted result and a short and concise definition of the problem (rules, constraints etc.). Nobody is going to "correct" imperative-style code that is simply uncorrectable in a functional settings.

Comment: @Dimitre: Hope it is better now.

Comment: @Robert: Not exactly: It isn't clear how the output after the inner-loop is produced -- this is absent in the code you show. As I said before, we don't have and *shouldn't* discuss your code at all -- especially when you haven't expained what it should be doing.

Comment: @Robert: It is not productive to ask a question, when you have no xml source document and you also have not defined what the required result should be. Providing incomplete code (the purpose of which is unknown) complicates the things even further.

Comment: @Dimitre: I would suggest re-read my post for a second time. I think I already highlighted "The initial XML is a blank file", and it is a "painting" process, so data will be grabbed from the those xml sources and insert it into the blank xml. Then how can you ask me to provide a xml source document? The data sources contains millions of code, which is not suitable to post here. If you do not like my question, please feel free to mark down my question or even vote to delete. At the same time, thank you for always paying attention to my question.

Comment: @Dimitre: If it is not so clear, why Alejandro could answer my question perfectly and I actually learned a lot from his answer? I wouldn't surrender to superiority, I know you are an expert out of experts in this field, but I believe everyone begins with 0.

Comment: @Dimitre: I think it is not productive to post such a comment, when I couldn't find useful feedback but only felt degraded.

Comment: @Robert: I really don't care whether you take notice of the issues you have in defining questions well, or not. This affects you, not me. It is true that @Alejandro has good abilities as a clairevoyant, and if you decide to rely that people will always be willing to guess what your problem is, you are severely degrading your chances of receiving a timely and correct answer. Once again, this is *your* problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple solution without the need to explain the differences between imperative and declarative paradigm, is a two-phase transformation. This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
 exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="vRTF-FirstPass">
            <Outer>
                <HL>
                    <HL01/>
                </HL>
                <Inner>
                    <HL01/>
                </Inner>
                <HL>
                    <HL01/>
                </HL>
            </Outer>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:apply-templates
             select="msxsl:node-set($vRTF-FirstPass)/node()"
             mode="second-pass"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="second-pass">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="second-pass"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="HL01" mode="second-pass">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="vPosition">
                <xsl:number level="any"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="$vPosition + 1"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With any input (not used), output:

```
<Outer>
    <HL>
        <HL01>1</HL01>
    </HL>
    <Inner>
        <HL01>2</HL01>
    </Inner>
    <HL>
        <HL01>3</HL01>
    </HL>
</Outer>
```

**Note**: The use of `node-set()` extension function (look for the right namespace URI for your XSLT processor implementation, or just upgrade your enviroment to XSLT 2.0 and forget `node-set()`). Modes just in case. Of course, you should output inside `$vRTF-FirstPass` variable all your desired output whether by `apply-templates`, `call-template` or... whatever.

**EDIT**: You could replace "HL01" rule with this other similar but shorter content template:

```
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::HL01) + 2"/>
</xsl:copy>
```

Comment: @Alejandro: worked great. I think two-phase translation is a good workaround for counting segments in xslt.

Comment: @Robert: I'm glad it was helpful. Properly, this is function composition as in `(f o g)(x) = f( g(x) )`. It's not a workaround, but a basic pattern in declarative paradigm.